# Facebook Conceal - Image Encryption and Decryption

Tags: android, facebook, encryption

I am trying to encrypt and decrypt image using Facebook Conceal Library. This is the first time i am using it and hence bear with me if its trivial. I have looked at other questions on SO to figure out the reasons for my exceptions, my i couldn't  get it working.

Here is what I have done till now...

Integrating: I am using Eclipse and hence, downloaded crypto.jar and libs.zip from [here](http://facebook.github.io/conceal/documentation/) and added the jar file to libs folder and .so files to respective folder inside libs folder.

My scenario:

I have to capture an image from camera, encrypt and store it on my phone memory. Decrypt it and show it in an imageview. At a later stage, i also need to decrypt this image from the memory and send it over network.

So, my code goes as below...

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (Const.DEBUGGING) {
        Log.d(Const.DEBUG, "RequestCode: " + requestCode + "\nResultCode:"
                + resultCode);
    }

    int tag = getRecordCount();
    tag++;

    if (requestCode == KTP_PICTURE_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            ENCRYPTEDFILENAME = tag + "_" + KTP_TAG + ".png";

            saveFile((Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"), requestCode);
            Bitmap decryptedImage = decodeFile(ENCRYPTEDFILENAME);
            mImgBtnKtppicture.setImageBitmap(decryptedImage);

        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            if (Const.DEBUGGING)
                Log.d(Const.DEBUG, "KTP_RESULT CANCELED");
        } else {

        }
    }

    if (requestCode == PROFILE_PICTURE_REQUEST_CODE) {

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            ENCRYPTEDFILENAME = tag + "_" + PROFILE_TAG + ".png";

            saveFile((Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"), requestCode);
            Bitmap decryptedImage = decodeFile(ENCRYPTEDFILENAME);
            mImgBtnPicture.setImageBitmap(decryptedImage);

        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            if (Const.DEBUGGING)
                Log.d(Const.DEBUG, "PICTURE_RESULT CANCELED");
        } else {

        }

    }
}
```

SaveFile():

```
public void saveFile(Bitmap photo, int code) {

    try {
        ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
        File directory = cw.getDir(DIRECTORY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        File mypath = new File(directory, ENCRYPTEDFILENAME);

        if (code == KTP_PICTURE_REQUEST_CODE) {
            mKtppicture = Uri.fromFile(mypath).toString();

            if (Const.DEBUGGING)
                Log.d(Const.DEBUG, "KTP Picture Path: " + mKtppicture);
        } else if (code == PROFILE_PICTURE_REQUEST_CODE) {
            mPicture = Uri.fromFile(mypath).toString();

            if (Const.DEBUGGING)
                Log.d(Const.DEBUG, "Profile Picture Path: " + mPicture);
        }


        Crypto crypto = new Crypto(
                  new SharedPrefsBackedKeyChain(this),
                  new SystemNativeCryptoLibrary());


        if (!crypto.isAvailable()) {
              return;
            }

        OutputStream fileStream = new BufferedOutputStream(
                  new FileOutputStream(mypath));

        OutputStream outputStream = crypto.getCipherOutputStream(
                  fileStream, new Entity("Password"));

        ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream);
        objectOutputStream.write(bitmapToBytes(photo));

        objectOutputStream.close(); //Line with exception
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

bitmapToBytes():

```
private byte[] bitmapToBytes(Bitmap photo) {

    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

    return byteArray;
}
```

decodeFile():

```
private Bitmap decodeFile(String filename) {

    Crypto crypto = new Crypto(
              new SharedPrefsBackedKeyChain(this),
              new SystemNativeCryptoLibrary());

    ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
    File directory = cw.getDir(DIRECTORY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    File file = new File(directory, filename);

    try{
        FileInputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        InputStream inputStream = crypto.getCipherInputStream(
                  fileStream,
                  new Entity("Password"));
        ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream);
        Bitmap bitmap = bytesToBitmap((byte[])objectInputStream.readObject());

        return bitmap;
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

bytesToBitmap():

```
private Bitmap bytesToBitmap(byte[] bytes) {

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
    return bitmap;
}
```

When i try to save the image, i get a UnsupportedOperationException at `objectOutputStream.close();` in saveFile()

Logcat Trace:

```
10-01 16:55:34.529: W/System.err(31291): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
10-01 16:55:34.529: W/System.err(31291):    at com.facebook.crypto.streams.NativeGCMCipherOutputStream.write(NativeGCMCipherOutputStream.java:93)
10-01 16:55:34.529: W/System.err(31291):    at java.io.DataOutputStream.writeByte(DataOutputStream.java:144)
10-01 16:55:34.529: W/System.err(31291):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.drain(ObjectOutputStream.java:394)
10-01 16:55:34.529: W/System.err(31291):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.flush(ObjectOutputStream.java:461)
10-01 16:55:34.529: W/System.err(31291):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.close(ObjectOutputStream.java:337)
10-01 16:55:34.529: W/System.err(31291):    at com.xx.xxx.RegistrationActivity.saveFile(RegistrationActivity.java:761)
10-01 16:55:34.529: W/System.err(31291):    at com.xx.xxx.RegistrationActivity.onActivityResult(RegistrationActivity.java:639)
10-01 16:55:34.529: W/System.err(31291):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5423)
10-01 16:55:34.529: W/System.err(31291):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3347)
10-01 16:55:34.529: W/System.err(31291):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3394)
10-01 16:55:34.529: W/System.err(31291):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:135)
10-01 16:55:34.529: W/System.err(31291):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1244)
10-01 16:55:34.529: W/System.err(31291):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-01 16:55:34.529: W/System.err(31291):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-01 16:55:34.529: W/System.err(31291):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
10-01 16:55:34.529: W/System.err(31291):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-01 16:55:34.529: W/System.err(31291):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-01 16:55:34.529: W/System.err(31291):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
10-01 16:55:34.529: W/System.err(31291):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
10-01 16:55:34.529: W/System.err(31291):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-01 16:55:34.529: W/System.err(31291): java.io.IOException: Unexpected crypto version -1
10-01 16:55:34.529: W/System.err(31291):    at com.facebook.crypto.util.Assertions.checkArgumentForIO(Assertions.java:29)
10-01 16:55:34.539: W/System.err(31291):    at com.facebook.crypto.CipherHelper.getCipherInputStream(CipherHelper.java:52)
10-01 16:55:34.539: W/System.err(31291):    at com.facebook.crypto.Crypto.getCipherInputStream(Crypto.java:83)
10-01 16:55:34.539: W/System.err(31291):    at com.xx.xxx.RegistrationActivity.decodeFile(RegistrationActivity.java:821)
10-01 16:55:34.539: W/System.err(31291):    at com.xx.xxx.RegistrationActivity.onActivityResult(RegistrationActivity.java:640)
10-01 16:55:34.539: W/System.err(31291):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5423)
10-01 16:55:34.539: W/System.err(31291):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3347)
10-01 16:55:34.539: W/System.err(31291):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3394)
10-01 16:55:34.539: W/System.err(31291):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:135)
10-01 16:55:34.539: W/System.err(31291):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1244)
10-01 16:55:34.539: W/System.err(31291):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-01 16:55:34.539: W/System.err(31291):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-01 16:55:34.539: W/System.err(31291):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
10-01 16:55:34.539: W/System.err(31291):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-01 16:55:34.539: W/System.err(31291):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-01 16:55:34.539: W/System.err(31291):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
10-01 16:55:34.549: W/System.err(31291):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
10-01 16:55:34.549: W/System.err(31291):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-01 16:55:34.549: D/BAT(31291): onResume called
```

Thanks for your help...

Comment: OutputStream outputStream = crypto.getCipherOutputStream(
                  fileStream, new Entity("Password")); .. is this correct way of doing it. I think the last parameter, Entity, is a cipher. So, for testing, i am using "Password"

Comment: Unsupported operation exception could just point to the wrong runtime level being used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how i solved the problem.. encryption and decryption works fine now.

```
// Encrypts the image and saves to directory

public void encodeAndSaveFile(Bitmap photo, int code) {

    try {
        ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
        File directory = cw.getDir(DIRECTORY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        File mypath = new File(directory, ENCRYPTEDFILENAME);

        Crypto crypto = new Crypto(new SharedPrefsBackedKeyChain(this),
                new SystemNativeCryptoLibrary());

        if (!crypto.isAvailable()) {
            return;
        }

        OutputStream fileStream = new BufferedOutputStream(
                new FileOutputStream(mypath));
        OutputStream outputStream = crypto.getCipherOutputStream(
                fileStream, new Entity("Password"));
        outputStream.write(bitmapToBytes(photo));
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (UnsupportedOperationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

// convert Bitmap to bytes
private byte[] bitmapToBytes(Bitmap photo) {

    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
    return byteArray;
}

// convert bytes to Bitmap
private Bitmap bytesToBitmap(byte[] bytes) {

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);

    return bitmap;
}

// decode encrypted file and returns Bitmap
private Bitmap decodeFile(String filename) {

    Crypto crypto = new Crypto(new SharedPrefsBackedKeyChain(this),
            new SystemNativeCryptoLibrary());

    ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
    File directory = cw.getDir(DIRECTORY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    File file = new File(directory, filename);

    try {
        FileInputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        InputStream inputStream = crypto.getCipherInputStream(fileStream,
                new Entity("Password"));

        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        int read;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        while ((read = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }

        inputStream.close();

        Bitmap bitmap = bytesToBitmap(out.toByteArray());
        return bitmap;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Here is how i am calling encodeAndSaveFile() and decodeFile(), in onActivityResult(), after returning from camera.

```
encodeAndSaveFile((Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"),
                        requestCode);
Bitmap decryptedImage = decodeFile(ENCRYPTEDFILENAME);
```

Comment: ,what was the reason of this exception , can you please elaborate on this .

Comment: I am still following byte wise decryption , still getting this error .Possible difference in the code of question and answer here.

Comment: This is a code-only answer, and as such this is not constructive in any way.