# offline drm. using exoplayer for offline secure content

Tags: android, video-streaming, drm, exoplayer

Can I Download a video with DRM protection on SD card and play it only with my app that using Exoplayer or in someway that video saved securely. I don't want user can copy my video to another device and I want save it on SD card because of sizes and number of videos user may download

Comment: Hi Siavash, Have u got any solution ?

Comment: @PrabhuM not for offline DRM but I write an answer. maybe it works for you too.

Comment: This issue on ExoPlayer's repository might help https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/949

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the latest release of ExoPlayer 2.2.0 , it provides this facility inbuilt in ExoPlayer.
ExoPlayer has a helper class to download and refresh offline license keys

```
OfflineLicenseHelper.java
/**
 * Helper class to download, renew and release offline licenses. It utilizes {@link
 * DefaultDrmSessionManager}.
 */
public final class OfflineLicenseHelper<T extends ExoMediaCrypto> {
```

You can access the latest code from the [ExoPlayer repo](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer)

For more inspiration you can look at this closed [issue](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/949).

I created a sample application for Offline playback of DRM content.You can access it from [here](https://github.com/ashwanijanghu/ExoPlayer-Offline)

Comment: could you provide an example with more detail info?

Comment: @HamedGh I did updated my answer. You can have a look.

Comment: As google said: On Android 4.4 (API level 19) and higher, ExoPlayer supports Digital Rights Managment (DRM) protected playback. but you set minSdkVersion to 16, why? does it works for api 16?

Comment: @HamedGh : Yeah that's an Honest mistake, I will update that. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Exoplayer for offline viewing. But you will have to extend your own class from `DrmSessionManager`. The Key here is to use `MediaDrm.KEY_TYPE_OFFLINE` as a keyType in `mediaDrm.getKeyRequest`.

In the `mediaDrm.provideKeyResponse` you need to get the `KeySetId` and used later when another request for the same video is made `mediaDrm.restoreKeys`

Also don't forget to set the state of the player with `STATE_OPENED_WITH_KEYS` after restoring the keys.

You can find more informations about this here: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaDrm.html#KEY_TYPE_OFFLINE
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaDrm.html#restoreKeys(byte[],byte[])

Answer (score 1):

For now I decide to use [Facebook conceal library](https://github.com/facebook/conceal). fast and easy way for encryption. I download my content and pass it to conceal library and when I want to play the video use byte stream for and read video sectional.

but if you find better and easier way let me know.

you can find an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26140389/facebook-conceal-image-encryption-and-decryption)

Comment: The example you provided is for image, how to implement it for video which user want to change progress to any time

Comment: @HamedGh you can break one video to several 15 secs videos for example. and then encrypt and decrypt it. I know it's not a good solution. so you can use drm and pls see accepted answer.